# Locale not changing when redirect() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a switch language button in my app.

Here is my controller:

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{

public function update($locale){
    app()->setLocale($locale);
    return redirect()->back();

}
```

}

When I dd my $locale, it has the new $locale value, but when it redirects, it resets $locale.

If I change return redirect()->back() to fixed url: return view('auth.login') it works.

So, I don't understand why it happens, any idea???

Answer (score 1):

setlocale only works for the current page it isn't saved for the next page.

You should make middleware that runs on every page and set the locale there.

A nice example of how to do it can be found [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-to-setlocale-in-laravel-5-on-multilingual-multidomain-app).

Comment: I don't understand it... I had it before in a Middleware.... But basically, I have 2 case, if the user is authenticated, I have his preference in DB. So, in the case he is a guest, how should the session get the new value in the example you sent me???

Comment: Put it in a session variable.